# Image overlay on background to auto resize to size on mobile device

Tags: html, css

I have a background image and a logo image which is added on top of the background. On desktop, the both pictures display as expected but on mobile devices the logo width is stretched causing the menu to display out of proportion. I've played around with css to try resolve this but to no avail.

HTML

```
<!-- banner -->
<div class="banner2"> //Main Background image
        <div class="container">

        <div class="w3l-banner-grids">

            <img src="/Content/MyTemplate/images/TransparentLogo.png" style="height:450px;"  /> //Logo - overlay image

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- //banner -->
```

CSS

```
.banner2 {
    background-image: url(../../Images/CloudyCross.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    padding: 1em 0;
}

img.img-responsive {
    width: 100%;
}
```

This is how it displays on mobile, how can I adjust the width for mobile without affecting the width on desktop?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide more information like your "img-responsive" class?
Without this information I think you could try with multiple background images. So you can also remove some html tags.

Comment: Hi, please check edit. I've added it

Comment: looks like your banner div doesn't go the full width of the page, but it's hard to tell without a [mcve] so I'm voting to close

Answer (score 0):

Just add this in your code. Hope this helps!

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean something like this:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  background: url("/Content/MyTemplate/images/TransparentLogo.png") top center / auto 30% no-repeat, url("../../Images/CloudyCross.jpg") center / cover
}
```

see
https://codepen.io/Kani/pen/omJrbQ

Otherwise when you need a fine grade control try media queries:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .img-responsive {
        width: 50%
    }
}
```